# Loopback API - can I alter what is shown in the API?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

Say I have a collection where I continuously add (insert()) documents on a daily basis, that I would like to show as arrays in Loopback, how would I do this? Am I missing something here with the models?

For example I now have collections like this:

```
Datefrom: 2017-06-02T07:20:32.000Z,
DateTo: 2017-06-02T08:40:09.000Z,
EndNumber: 2400,
StartNumber: 1296
```

That I would like to show up as part of one big array like:

```
[["2017-06-02T07:20:32.000Z","2017-06-02T08:40:09.000Z",2400,1296,45977],
["2017-06-02T07:20:32.000Z","2017-06-02T08:40:09.000Z",2400,1296,45977]]
```

Can this be done or do I need to save my documents as part of one big array in a document instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is common that the REST API response of a collection request is an array of objects. Then in the client you can manipulate it however you want.
If you insist of manipulating the response in the server you can do it with remote method hooks. (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html)